# Going live with a new Magento theme on live after development on dev server

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

My company has a live Magento site (1.7.0.2) with active customers buying products every day.

We have replicated the live environment onto a development server and applied a new theme.

Now, after testing, we want to go live.

How do we get the changes we made on dev (theme and config of theme and its new static blocks and the files etc.) to now apply to the live site but maintain all the new orders and products and product changes?

Thanks for any guidance or examples!

Comment: Copy new files to live ftp and change settings in Magento backend. Static blocks are stored in database.

Comment: This question belongs on magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Steve is very probably correct, magento.stackexchange.com is likely the best place for this question. However, the technical community here have already helped me massively with magento questions. How could I have made the question clearer or more useful? And then, do I bother changing it now, or simply re-ask on magento.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a list/script a solution of all the database changes that are made (configs, cms blocks, pages, etc).  Unfortunately there isn't a very easy way to deploy configs (though Enterprise has a staging feature).

After that

1. Put live site in maintenance mode by creating a `maintenance.flag` file in the root of the application

   1. I'll typically modify `index.php` to allow my IP past the maintenance
2. Deploy the theme's code
3. Apply database changes
4. Test
5. Remove `mainenance.flag`